# Should I "copy project into workspace" external Android libraries or use the default root location?

Tags: android, eclipse

When importing libraries like `appcompat`, which are maintained and updated by SDK manager, into a workspace should I `copy them into the workspace` or use from their `root location`? If I copy it into my workspace and if Google updates it then I will have to manually update it too, so it seems leaving them in their root location like `~/sdk/extras/.../appcompat` sounds like a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my opinion, but I think it would be far better to copy the library for a single, **very** good reason: you don't want the android tool to update the dependencies of your project, but it's something you really want to take in your hands instead.

Should you need more convincing think about this scenario:

You have project A and B, both using the same library, linked to the same directory.

Maybe you are working on C, when you find out that google udpated the library and this will probably fix a terrible bug in your project. Months later you go back to project A, and you find out that it's not working anymore.

Now, after all that time, what are the odds of you remembering that you updated the libraries one month before? :)

Oh, and let's not mention the odds of getting the "old" version of the library (should you not be using a code revision system) to make A work again...

Hope this helps